# Alias с параметрами

Tags: linux, bash, alias

Сейчас если набираю в командной строке `eslint_d 'src/**/*.ts'` то в ответ выходит:
`✖ 12 problems (0 errors, 12 warnings)`

готовлю `alias` которая будет являться частью другой команды (здесь я опустил флаги как незначащие вопросу).
`alias esLint='f(){ eslint_d "$@"**/*.ts; unset -f f; }; f'`,

предполагается что будет использоваться `esLint src/` которая должна вызвать вышеприведенную команду.
Но выполнение команды выводит следующее:
`✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)`
В итоге псевдоним сканирует только первый уровень папки не входя в дочерние.
Как решить вопрос?

Comment: Алиас с параметром - это функция

Comment: ну вообще вам же только первый параметр надо подставить, а не список из всех параметров: `$ alias esLint='f(){ eslint_d \"$1**/*.ts\"; unset -f f; }; f'`; и эта ваша программа требует, чтобы ей параметр передавался в кавычках. поэтому, возможно, обратных слэшей надо будет больше — пробуйте.